# setting QComboBox size more than one items

Tags: c++, qt, combobox

I want QComboBox size to be more than 1. By default it is 1. From "size" I mean It should show more than one options at a time without mouse-click on comboBox. I could not find any function on [QComboBox Doc](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qcombobox.html). For what behaviour I want  can be understood by this html code.In HTML it is done this way.

```
 <select size="3">
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="opel">Opel</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
```

[Link to this source](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select_size) . Look at the result on right side.

What should I do to achieve such a "Select from list" functionality in qt?

Comment: But it is QListWidget or QListView

Comment: Looks like a [`QListView`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qlistview.html) or [`QListWidget`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qlistwidget.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this. `QComboBox` is just a `QLineEdit` with down-arrow button, popup menu(view) which described by model (`QStandardItemModel` etc).

`QLineEdit` doesn't allow you to show more then one line.

You should use `QListWidget` for easy tasks and `QListView` for harder tasks. It is very similar to your example.

You can get links from `@thuga's` comment. Documentation contains all necessary things such as `itemChanged ( QListWidgetItem * item )` signal and other examples.

I think that the maximum what you can achieve with `QComboBox` is just keep this `comboBox` open every time. Use `showPopup()` method for this.

Comment: Actually I expected this in QComboBox because of <Select ...> tag in html. Which have the such an option. I will try both QComboBox and QLineEdit to see which is appropriate for me.